# No value given For one or more required parameters (dataadapter.fill(dt))

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

```
da.fill(log_in)    
    Sql="select * from tblinfo where [Acc_ no]='& lblaccno &'"

Error in line = da.fill(log_in)
No value given for one or mote required parameters
```

My project in vb.net with ms access

Comment: If you are trying to use that Select command to .fill` whatever `log_in` is then think. How is the `.fill` supposed to know what to do when the select follows the `.fill`. Code executes in order from top to bottom.

Comment: Can u give me ur phone number sir

Comment: We need a bit more code to help. Maybe the entire method. Not the whole program. Also, if you get an error you must let us know what the error is. If you had taken the tour that was suggested to you, you would know this.

Comment: No, that is not the way Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Is lblaccno a variable? What type is it?

Comment: Always use parameters. This save you from errors concatenating strings as you had here. "select * from tblinfo where [Acc_ no]='& lblaccno &'" You used the ampersand character to concatenate a string but you put the whole thing inside the string (between the opening and closing double quotes. Parameters will also protect your database from sql injection which can destroy your data.

Comment: lblaccountno is Label

Comment: Dear mam or sir tommorow morning i will send u photo of this code and error stay tunre with me

Comment: Do not post images of code. Add the code to your question as text and format as code.

Comment: You cannot pass a label (a control) as a parameter to an sql command.

Answer (score 0):

try this order.

```
Sql="select * from tblinfo where [Acc_ no]='& lblaccno &'"
da.fill (log_in)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space and use the correct syntax:

```
Sql="select * from tblinfo where [Acc_no]='" & lblaccno & "'"
```